# Is there a way to update items in an array with JsonPatch?

Tags: javascript, json, json-patch, jsonpointer

The API to be invoked uses `JsonPatch`. The following is a sample `JSON`.

```
  { "hello": false
  , "array1": 
    [ { "subarray": [ "k2", "k1"] } 
    , { "subarray": [ "k1"] } 
    ] 
  }
```

I would like to **update both the subarrays** (elements of the `array1`). There could be N number of elements/items in `array1` that I'm not aware of when calling this API.

Now I can do the following if I am aware of the the size of `array1`.

```
 [{ "op": "add", "path": "/array1/0/subarray/0", "value": "gk" }]
 [{ "op": "add", "path": "/array1/1/subarray/0", "value": "gk" }]
```

But since I'm **not aware of the the size** of `array1`, it does not seem that this can be achieved using JsonPointer. Is there something that can be done to do an update that targets all the elements of `array1` (i.e all the subarrays) in one go? Something like this:

```
 [{ "op": "add", "path": "/array1/*/subarray1/0", "value": "gk-new" }]
```

After invocation, the resulting subarrays should have an additional element *"gk-new"* in addition to what they have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no wildcard support in JsonPatch or JsonPointer. Therefore, what is asked in the question is not possible.